# Why is my App crashing with a NullPointerException in my ButtonManager class?

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

I'm making a small Quiz Game and I didn't want to make every function for the Buttons in every Activity, because don't repeat yourself. But when I launch my App it crashes with a Null Pointer Exception.

I tried the Solution at the Bottom and aswell created a function in the ButtonManager class where I had as constructor parameter a String and converted it in the function named above.

This is what my ButtonManager class looks like:

```
class ButtonManager(buttonName: Int) : AppCompatActivity() {

    val button: Button = findViewById(buttonName)

    fun quitGame(){

        finish()
    }
}
```

This is what my functions call looks like in my Activity:

```
ButtonManager(R.id.quitGameButton).button.setOnClickListener {
    ButtonManager(R.id.quitGameButton).quitGame()
}
```

This is the Error Code:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Do you call setcontentview?

Comment: No, i don't call it anywhere

Comment: if there is no layout visible then you cant use "findviewbyId" since there are no views yet.

Comment: How can I add a setContentView() at my ButtonManager class

Comment: you could pass a reference of your button (instead of its name) to your buttonmanager class.

Comment: It's a unresolved reference, because it wants to know where the button is.

Comment: its not needed to know where it is, you just need to know when the button was pressed.

Comment: val button: Button = findViewById(buttonName) I can't do it this way. Maybe I'm retarded but I don't know how you mean it

Comment: ButtonManager(findViewById(R.id.buttonid))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing some fundamental concepts for android.

I assume you just want to add a clicklistener to your button. In that case you don't need your Button manager class at all.

In your Activity you can simply add:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){

        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout) // xml layout with a Button with android:I'd=" @+I'd/quitGameButton"

        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.quitGameButton)
        button.onClickListener{
                finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No i don't want to add a click listener to my Button